# SqlMembershipProvider web.config Issue

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security, administration

I'm configuring the `SqlMembershipProvider` for asp.net and I in my `web.config` file I don't have the ability to add `connectionStringName` attribute. I'm supposed to having this and if I don't put it in there I get an exception from the website administration tool saying that the `connectionStringName` value is empty or not set. Is there a reason as to why I don't have the `connectionStringName` in the `web.config`?

It's supposed to look like this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add type="System.Web.Security.SqlmembershipProvider" name="MyMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MusicStoreEntities"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

but I don't have the `connectionStringName`....Any ideas?

btw - When I say that I don't have it, it's not displaying in intellisense.

Comment: Just add it manually... intellisense in VS is not perfect - some things aren't shown....

Comment: Hi Marc, not for sure how to make your comment accepted answer, but you were right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please refer this msdn article on setting up membership provider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t.aspx
 As far as intellisense is concerned there may be some other error in the web.config that is causing the intellisense not to work.